# C parser recursion

Tags: c, recursion, lisp

I'm making a simple program in C an Lisp arithmetic calculator just involving integers and `"+ - * /"` operators, I'm doing this for learning purposes it's not my homework or something like that.

So I have made a function which will correctly parse something like this `(+ 2 3)` it would output 5, so I know how to handle non nested statements but what when I have something like this `(+ (* 2 3) (- 4 2))` so it seems like I can use recursion to solve this, but I don't know really how to do it.

My logic is following(in pseudo code):`

```
  function parse_line(int n)
    get_input(string);
    if string[n] == '('
     if string[n+1] == operator
      if string[n+3] == number
       result = parseAllNumbers(); //between ( )
       return result; 
    if string[n+3] == '('
     parse_line(n+2);
```

`

So is my logic correct here, if I have `(+ (* 2 3) (- 4 2))` I would just calc. `(* 2 3)`, how would I go about calculating the `(- 4 2)` and then adding those two result together

Comment: What is `(-4 2)` supposed to mean?

Comment: 4 - 2 acctualy it would be (- 4 2) with that space between the minus and a 4.

Comment: @user1599217 In your original post, is it supposed to be `(-4 2)` or `(- 4 2)`?

Comment: the second one I fixed it now, sorry about that, I got the idea of that structure from Scheme language.

Comment: As an aside: You do know that polish notation has the advantage of not requiring parentheses for disambiguation? `+ * 2 3 - 4 2` is good enough (although in this case, there never was ambiguity in the first place).

Comment: Actually I'm just know reading the wiki about polish notation, scheme uses parentheses so...that's why.

Comment: Ah! Alright. I don't know Scheme.

Comment: I'm guessing you're supposed to be using recursion and not something different like a stack?  Once you have one solution, it's sometimes interesting to figure out how else you could solve the same problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're definitely on the right track.

Assume that we have a `getToken()` function written which reads the next logical token in the string from the current position.  A logical token would be a number, '(', ')' or any of the four operators.  Then we can recursively evaluate expressions.

```
function evaluateExpression(){
    var token = getToken();

    if( isNumber(token)){
        return token;
    }else if( isOpenParen(token)){
        return evaluateExpression();
    }

    var numOne = evaluateExpression();
    var nextToken = null;
    while( !isRightParen(nextToken)){
        nextToken = getToken();
        numOne = evaluate(token, numOne, nextToken);
    }

    return numOne;
}
```

The functions `isNumber()` and `isLeftParen()` do what they imply, return true if the token passed to it is a number or left parenthesis respectively.  The `evaluate()` function takes the operator token as well as the two numbers to evaluate them.  Eg, `evaluate(+,2,4)` would return `6` and `evaluate(-,2,4)` would return `2`.

Comment: Hmm thanks for the help, but  it doesn't have to be just 2 operand (+ 2 3 4 5) this expression is also valid.

Comment: Don't give up so easily, we can easily modify this...  By the way, I did not know that'd be a valid expression (with only one operator)

Comment: I appreciate your help, I won't give up. That expression is valid in Scheme and that's what I was going for, I was actually watching a lecture about scheme and thought that this would be a good exercise in C.

Comment: Good idea, that's a great way to exercise your programming skills.  I updated my answer to offer a little bit of help.  The recursion will simply be based on the rules that make up valid expressions.  Try and understand all the possibilities and valid statements before designing your algorithm.  This is a perfect example for recursion

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that uses recursion:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define OPERATOR 0
#define OPEN_PAREN 1
#define CLOSE_PAREN 2
#define NUMBER 3
#define END_OF_EXPR 4

#define BAD_LINE 1
#define GOOD_LINE 0




typedef struct 
{
   unsigned char type;
   char operator;
   int number;
} token;

token tokens[100];
int num_tokens = 0;
int token_counter = 0;

token get_token(void)
{

   token temp;
   if ( token_counter < num_tokens )
   {
      temp = tokens[token_counter];
      token_counter += 1;
   }
   else
   {
      temp.type = END_OF_EXPR;
   }
   return temp;
}


int tokenize(const char *line, token *tokens,int *num_tokens)
{
   token_counter = 0;
   int number_digit = 0;
   token aToken;
   int length = strlen(line);
   char number_array[20];
   *num_tokens = 0;
   int num_open_paren = 0;
   int num_close_paren = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
   {
      /* ignore whitespace */
      if ( line[i] == ' ' || line[i] == '\t' || line[i] == '\n' || line[i] == '\r' )
      {
         if ( number_digit > 0 )
         {
            number_array[number_digit] = '\0';
            aToken.number = atoi(number_array);
            aToken.type = NUMBER;
            tokens[*num_tokens] = aToken;
            *num_tokens += 1;       
            number_digit = 0;   
         }
      }
      else if ( line[i] == '(')
      {
         aToken.type = OPEN_PAREN;
         tokens[*num_tokens] = aToken;
         *num_tokens += 1;
         num_open_paren += 1;
      }
      else if (line[i] == ')' )
      {
         if ( number_digit > 0 )
         {
            number_array[number_digit] = '\0';
            aToken.number = atoi(number_array);
            aToken.type = NUMBER;
            tokens[*num_tokens] = aToken;
            *num_tokens += 1;           
            number_digit = 0;
         }
         aToken.type = CLOSE_PAREN;
         tokens[*num_tokens] = aToken;
         *num_tokens += 1;
         num_close_paren += 1;
      }
      else if ( line[i] == '*' || line[i] == '+' ||  
           line[i] == '/' || line[i] == '-' )
      {
         aToken.type = OPERATOR;
         aToken.operator = line[i];
         tokens[*num_tokens] = aToken;
         *num_tokens += 1;       
      }
      else if ( isdigit(line[i]) )
      {
         number_array[number_digit] = line[i];
         number_digit += 1;
      }
      else
      {
         printf("%c - the %d character - is illegal\n",line[i],i+1);
         return BAD_LINE;
      }

   }
   if ( num_open_paren == num_close_paren )
   {
      return GOOD_LINE;
   }
   else
   {
      printf("mismatched parentheses\n:%s\n",line);
      return BAD_LINE;
   }
}


int evaluate(char operator, int *operands, int num_operands)
{
   int result = 0;
   switch (operator)
   {    
      case '+':
         for (int i = 0; i < num_operands; i++)
         {
            result += operands[i];
         }
         break;
      case '-':
         result = operands[0];
         for (int i = 1; i < num_operands; i++)
         {
            result -= operands[i];
         }
         break;
      case '*':
         result = operands[0];
         for (int i = 1; i < num_operands; i++)
         {
            result *= operands[i];
         }    
         break;
      case '/':
         result = operands[0];
         for (int i = 1; i < num_operands; i++)
         {
            result /= operands[i];
         }    
         break;   
      default:
         printf("ERROR invalid operator: %c\n",operator);
   }
   return result;
}

int process_expression(void)
{
   int result = 0;
   token current_token = get_token();
   if ( current_token.type != OPERATOR )
   {
      fprintf(stderr,"ERROR: %s expecting operator\n",__func__);
      exit(1);
   }
   char operator = current_token.operator;
   current_token = get_token();
   int operands[200];
   int operands_index = 0;
   while ( current_token.type != CLOSE_PAREN && current_token.type != END_OF_EXPR)
   {
      if ( current_token.type == NUMBER )
      {
         operands[operands_index] = current_token.number;
         operands_index += 1;
      }
      else if ( current_token.type == OPEN_PAREN )
      {
         operands[operands_index] = process_expression();
         operands_index += 1;
      }
      current_token = get_token();
   }
   result = evaluate(operator,operands,operands_index);
   return result;
}

void process_lisp_string(const char *line)
{

   int result = tokenize(line, tokens,&num_tokens);

   if ( result == GOOD_LINE )
   {
      token first = get_token();
      if ( first.type == OPEN_PAREN )
         printf("the answer for %s is: %d\n",line, process_expression());
      else
      {
         fprintf(stderr,"ERROR: no open parentheses at front of expression\n");
         fprintf(stderr,"token type:%d\n",first.type);
      }
   }
   else 
   {
      printf("the line contained errors\n");
   }
}

int main(const int argc, const char *const argv[])
{
   char *test = "(+ 2 2 )";
   char *line = "(+ (+ 30 20) 2 2)";
   char *line2 = "(- (+ 1000 10) 200)";
   char *line3 = "(- (+ 1000 10) (- 200 10) (* 2 4))";
   char *line4 = "(+ (+ 10 10) (* 2 4) (* 2 3) (* 2 (- 3 1)))";
   process_lisp_string(test);
   process_lisp_string(line);
   process_lisp_string(line2);
   process_lisp_string(line3);
   process_lisp_string(line4);
}
```

output:

```
the answer for (+ 2 2 ) is: 4
the answer for (+ (+ 30 20) 2 2) is: 54
the answer for (- (+ 1000 10) 200) is: 810
the answer for (- (+ 1000 10) (- 200 10) (* 2 4)) is: 812
the answer for (+ (+ 10 10) (* 2 4) (* 2 3) (* 2 (- 3 1))) is: 38
```

Comment: Woa, thanks this is not homework, I choosed C because I wanted to practise it a little bit...this is very helpfull

Answer (score 1):

C is the most difficult language to use. Unless this is a homework assignment it is probably best tried in another higher-level language first. C lacks strings and also data structures like a stack. This processing is probably done more elegantly recursively as the other poster suggested, but I find non-recursion easier. Here is a partial solution that only processes positive integers and lacks some error handling:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define OPERATOR 0
#define OPEN_PAREN 1
#define CLOSE_PAREN 2
#define NUMBER 3

#define BAD_LINE 1
#define GOOD_LINE 0

typedef struct 
{
   unsigned char type;
   char operator;
   int number;
} token;




int get_tokens(const char *line, token *tokens,int *num_tokens)
{
   int number_digit = 0;
   token aToken;
   int length = strlen(line);
   char number_array[20];
   *num_tokens = 0;
   int num_open_paren = 0;
   int num_close_paren = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
   {
      /* ignore whitespace */
      if ( line[i] == ' ' || line[i] == '\t' || line[i] == '\n' || line[i] == '\r' )
      {
         if ( number_digit > 0 )
         {
            number_array[number_digit] = '\0';
            aToken.number = atoi(number_array);
            aToken.type = NUMBER;
            tokens[*num_tokens] = aToken;
            *num_tokens += 1;       
            number_digit = 0;   
         }
      }
      else if ( line[i] == '(')
      {
         aToken.type = OPEN_PAREN;
         tokens[*num_tokens] = aToken;
         *num_tokens += 1;
         num_open_paren += 1;
      }
      else if (line[i] == ')' )
      {
         if ( number_digit > 0 )
         {
            number_array[number_digit] = '\0';
            aToken.number = atoi(number_array);
            aToken.type = NUMBER;
            tokens[*num_tokens] = aToken;
            *num_tokens += 1;           
            number_digit = 0;
         }
         aToken.type = CLOSE_PAREN;
         tokens[*num_tokens] = aToken;
         *num_tokens += 1;
         num_close_paren += 1;
      }
      else if ( line[i] == '*' || line[i] == '+' ||  
           line[i] == '/' || line[i] == '-' )
      {
         aToken.type = OPERATOR;
         aToken.operator = line[i];
         tokens[*num_tokens] = aToken;
         *num_tokens += 1;       
      }
      else if ( isdigit(line[i]) )
      {
         number_array[number_digit] = line[i];
         number_digit += 1;
      }
      else
      {
         printf("%c - the %d character - is illegal\n",line[i],i+1);
         return BAD_LINE;
      }

   }
   if ( num_open_paren == num_close_paren )
   {
      return GOOD_LINE;
   }
   else
   {
      printf("mismatched parentheses\n:%s\n",line);
      return BAD_LINE;
   }
}

int process_expression(char operator, int *operands, int num_operands)
{
   int result = 0;
   switch (operator)
   {    
      case '+':
         for (int i = 0; i < num_operands; i++)
         {
            result += operands[i];
         }
         break;
      case '-':
         result = operands[0];
         for (int i = 1; i < num_operands; i++)
         {
            result -= operands[i];
         }
         break;
      case '*':
         result = operands[0];
         for (int i = 1; i < num_operands; i++)
         {
            result *= operands[i];
         }    
         break;
      case '/':
         result = operands[0];
         for (int i = 1; i < num_operands; i++)
         {
            result /= operands[i];
         }    
         break;   
      default:
         printf("ERROR invalid operator: %c\n",operator);
   }
   return result;
}

int process_tokens(token *tokens, int num_tokens)
{
   int result = 0;
   /* operators "stack" */
   char operators[100];
   /* "pointer" for current operator */
   int operator_index = -1;
   /* operands "stack" 1 row for each operator (set of parentheses) */
   int operands[100][20];
   /* how many operands for current expression? (current operator) */
   int expression_operands[100];
   for (int i = 0; i < num_tokens; i++)
   {
      if ( tokens[i].type == OPEN_PAREN )
      {
         operator_index += 1;
         expression_operands[operator_index] = 0;
      }
      else if ( tokens[i].type == CLOSE_PAREN )
      {
         result = process_expression(operators[operator_index], 
                                          &operands[operator_index][0],
                                          expression_operands[operator_index]);
         operator_index -= 1;
         if ( operator_index > -1 )
         {
            operands[operator_index][ expression_operands[operator_index] ] = result;
            expression_operands[operator_index] += 1;
         }
      }
      else if ( tokens[i].type == OPERATOR )
      {
         operators[operator_index] = tokens[i].operator;
      }
      else if ( tokens[i].type == NUMBER )
      {
         operands[operator_index][ expression_operands[operator_index] ] = tokens[i].number;
         expression_operands[operator_index] += 1;
      }
   }
   return result;
}

void process_lisp_string(const char *string)
{
   token tokens[100];
   int num_tokens = 0;
   int result = get_tokens(string, tokens,&num_tokens);

   if ( result == GOOD_LINE )
   {
      printf("the answer is: %d\n",process_tokens(tokens,num_tokens));
   }
   else 
   {
      printf("the string contained errors\n");
   }
}

int main(const int argc, const char *const argv[])
{

   char *line = "(+ (+ 30 20) 2 2)";
   char *line2 = "(- (+ 1000 10) 200)";
   char *line3 = "(- (+ 1000 10) (- 200 10) (* 2 4))";
   char *line4 = "(+ (+ 10 10) (* 2 4) (* 2 3) (* 2 (- 3 1)))";
   process_lisp_string(line);
   process_lisp_string(line2);
   process_lisp_string(line3);
   process_lisp_string(line4);

}
```

result:

```
the answer is: 54
the answer is: 810
the answer is: 812
the answer is: 38
```